# PHP Check If column filled

Tags: php

example I have table with column like this :

```
L1 | L2 | L3 | L4 | L5
2  |    | 1  |    |
```

I want, if 1 of the 5 columns filled with value then will do something.

In PHP code so far :

```
<?php

//query to get all value of column
while ($data = oci_fetch_array($//query))
{
$l1 = $data['L1'];
$l2 = $data['L2'];
$l3 = $data['L3'];
$l4 = $data['L4'];
$l5 = $data['L5'];
}

//How can I check if 1 of the 5 column filled ?
if(bla bla)
{
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/array_filter) to determine if there's any non-empty value in the array:

```
if (count(array_filter($data))) {
  // there's something inside
}
```

To find out which values are considered non-empty, look at [this conversion table](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting).

Comment: +1 Heck, that's elegant. Never thought that filter without parameter might be useful.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (is_null($variable){
//do something
}
```